# Do I need a foreach with MultipleIterator?

Tags: php, xpath, foreach, iterator

This is my code to look up a comment and write to a file and work fine.

```
$comment1 = $xpath->query('//*[comment() = "abc"]');
$comment2 = $xpath->query('//*[comment() = "cde"]');

$commentIterator = new MultipleIterator();
$commentIterator->attachIterator(new IteratorIterator($comment1));
$commentIterator->attachIterator(new IteratorIterator($comment2));

foreach ($commentIterator as $comments) {
    file_put_contents('page1.php', $dom->saveHTML($comments[0]));
    file_put_contents('page2.php', $dom->saveHTML($comments[1]));   
}
```

The problem is that the result is correct even if I have `file_put_contents` outside the foreach. $comments is a local variable inside the loop. Do I need the foreach?

This code works just as well with $comments outside foreach

```
$comment1 = $xpath->query('//*[comment() = "abc"]');
$comment2 = $xpath->query('//*[comment() = "cde"]');

$commentIterator = new MultipleIterator();
$commentIterator->attachIterator(new IteratorIterator($comment1));
$commentIterator->attachIterator(new IteratorIterator($comment2));

foreach ($commentIterator as $comments) {

}

file_put_contents('page1.php', $dom->saveHTML($comments[0]));
file_put_contents('page2.php', $dom->saveHTML($comments[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

What if, in your case you remove the `foreach`? In your current example, you iterate over it so if it has found atleast 1 child, `$comments` hold the last value it got filled with from the last iteration the `foreach` did. If you remove your `foreach` completely, `$comments` won't be available anymore.

Comment: If I delete foreach saves all the code in the files (because $dom->saveHTML and $comments[0] does not exist) and not what I want from xpath. Is my first code a good solution? Are $comments not a local variable in the foreach, how is it possible that I can reach it  outside foreach?